Graph API: How do I get sensitivityLabel list using graph api
I'm trying to get sensitivityLabel list using graph API.
I'm working on Graph Explorer to get proper REST url first.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-informationprotection-list-sensitivitylabels?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
I look through this guid and tried several url but failed.
I got failed with these urls.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/me/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels

These are the error response
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'informationProtection'.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2024-07-19T08:15:31",
        "request-id": "cb4a1134-b2af-4e74-9337-e65e142777c9",
        "client-request-id": "c7385ff6-bf4c-e989-3754-1b1a4e9bcba9"
    }
}
"error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2024-07-19T08:16:27",
        "request-id": "54ad97bd-8b45-44eb-a129-6a9a09e6eff7",
        "client-request-id": "7c3347bd-9dc6-ceca-9fd5-e12757890a3a"
    }
}

Please suggest.

Could you include more details like what error response you are getting when you ran above API calls?

I just included it!

Use beta endpoint, not v1.0. Maybe you will get another error :)

Initially, I too got errors when I ran those URLs in my environment like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels


GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/me/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels


To get sensitivityLabel list using graph API, the correct URLs should be
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels

Response:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userID/security/informationProtection/sensitivityLabels

Response:

